# Create new copy of existing Customer

Tags: acumatica

I need to create new Customers by mostly copying a select customer and modifying a few fields relevant to a custom Process.
Outside of the custom Process as an initial attempt to see if this is even possible to copy a Customer I have the following:

```
public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
{
    public PXAction<Customer> copyTest;
    [PXProcessButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Copy Test")]
    protected virtual void CopyTest()
    {
        var customer = Base.BAccount.Current;
        var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
        var cache = graph.BAccount.Cache;

        // Set field Defaults using CustomerMaint.CopyAccounts method
        graph.CopyAccounts(cache, customer);

        // Create new copy of current Customer
        var copyCustomer = (Customer)cache.CreateCopy(customer);

        // Modify key values
        copyCustomer.AcctCD = "COPY " + customer.AcctCD;
        copyCustomer.BAccountID = null;

        // Prevent "Customer Class Changed -- update Defaults?" dialog
        cache.SetStatus(copyCustomer, PXEntryStatus.Inserted);

        // Insert into cache
        // *** Exception occurs here ***
        copyCustomer = (Customer)cache.Insert(copyCustomer);

        // Modify additional fields as necessary by custom process
        // ...

        // Persist to database
        graph.Save.Press();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm currently encountering with this code as it currently is, is in the `cache.Insert(copyCustomer)` throws an exception:

```
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field CustomerClassID: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
```

I've tracked this down to be coming from the `CustomerClassDefaultInserting` function of the `CustomerMaint` graph at the point of `SalesPerson.Insert(sperson)`.  It appears this function is attempting to create the CustSalesPeople record for the Default Salesperson of the assigned Customer Class.

Is this even on the right path to copy a Customer or is there a better way? Or how to address the exception when Inserting the new customer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with copying the customer is more than just copying one object. There are many objects that need to be copied for the customer.

I copied your code and executed it. I commented out CopyAccounts as I would think it would be called on the cloned object, not on the existing customer.

The next error I received was Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Default Location value 8068 Error: Default Location '8068' cannot be found in the system.

This was due to cloning the other foreign key fields from the Customer record. DefLocationID is the default location for the customer. It is trying to set those keys as well, and cannot due to the restriction put on the Selector, requiring the location to be the same BAccountID as the record. DefAddressID, DefContactID, and other key fields will act the same way.

So to complete this, you would need to review all foreign keys on the Customer/BAccount that may be set, and then copy those objects and set them to the proper DAC's as well. Some information may not need to be copied, so I would just null those key fields and copy what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Nickolas Hook Like KRichardson pointed out because of all the PK/FK constraints you can't just copy the data you will have to do everything individually.

the other approach is to pull the data for the parent.